# Handling error in promise by checking the response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, response

I need to handle an error wherein the response is not appropriate in 'then' in the sample code below.

```
getData().then(response => transformData(response));
```

I need to probably do something like this. But, am confused about how to get hold of the 'response' present inside 'then'.

```
getData().then(response => transformData(response)).catch(() => if(!response.data) { dispatch({ type: 'some_action' });
}
```

How do I access the response outside 'then' and inside catch to dispatch another action?

Comment: You mean you only want to catch errors from the `transformData` step?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Currently you got three answers doing different things, because we can only guess what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can handle if the response is success but it doesn't has data on i, or if the request just got an error the catch statement can handle it :

```
getData()
  .then(response =>{
    if(!response.data) { 
     dispatch({ type: 'some_action_for_the_error', payload: response.error });
    } 
    else {
     transformData(response)
    }
  ).catch(( error ) =>{
    console.error(error);
    dispatch({ type: 'some_action_for_the_error', payload: error });
  }
```

Comment: OP probably wants an `if`/`else` though and not run `transformData` on an invalid response.

Comment: Yep i think i missed the else statement

Answer (score 0):

The .then() function can take two arguments. The first is a success callback, which you are using. The second is a failure callback, which is what you want.

```
getData().then(
  success => transformData(success),
  failure => doSomething(failure)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand that how Promise works. then() method has two functions. First is **success** and second is **failure**. Failure can be written with .**catch** in es6. Now first understand that catch only gets called for network failure, 500 error, 404 not found error. In that case there is no data to process.

But what you would want is 200 Ok but if data is missing. You have put code in success itself :

```
getData().then(response => {
  const res = transformData(response);
  if(!res.data) {
     // do your stuff
  }
   return res; // else normal behaviour
});
```